# How to represent attributes of a relationship in ERD

Tags: attributes, relationship, erd

As you know, there's some kind of attributes which cannot be attribute of any individual entity in a relationship. For example, a "customer" borrow a "CD" from the store. So the "ReturnedDate" attribute should be the attribute of the relationship.
So, how to represent this attribute in ERD with Crow's foot notation ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a diamond shaped box to represent the relationship, and put the attribute inside the diamond.

Comment: I think diamond shaped box is not Crow's foot notation

Comment: The two are not the same thing, but they are not mutually exclusive, either.